# Why is a nested event handler still firing if the parent event isn't being triggered, in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my site, I have the following snippet of jQuery/JavaScript:

```
$("span.testLink").mousedown(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 1) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $("span.testLink").mouseup(function (e) {
            if (e.which == 1) {
                var urlEncoded = encodeURI($(this).parent().find("input").val());
                window.open(urlEncoded);
            }
        });
        $(this).css("color", "#0b3773");
    }
});
```

It's pretty easy to tell what I expect to happen here (even though, clearly, my expectations are off somewhere), but for the sake of completeness: There is a link which should act as if it had the simple `.click()` event handler (because the `mouseup()` is nested within the `mousedown()` or so I *thought*). Apparently, this is not the way this works because I can click and hold down the left mouse button outside of the `span.testLink` element, drag back over the `span.testLink` element, then release the left mouse button and the `$("span.testLink").mouseup()` event still fires.

Clearly, I am in err as to when I expect this nested event to fire. My question is why and how should I be doing this differently?

**Additional Information:**

The `span.testLink` element, among others, are nested within a `jQueryUI` sortable element. Not sure if this matters or not, but thought it was definitely worth mentioning. If the answer to this question is "Nope, this *should* work. Check your plugin.", that is perfectly fine. I just need to make sure I understand how nested event handlers in jQuery work before I end up fouling something else up, if that is, indeed, the case.

Comment: Each time you call `.mouseup()`, you're adding *another* copy of the event handler for that element.  Other than that, setting up an event handler inside another event handler doesn't have any particular significance. What matters is the structure of the DOM. There's really no such thing as a "nested event handler".

Comment: You're not nesting event handlers there.  When there's a mousedown event, it *creates* the mouseup event handler, and it will always work after that.  Is there a reason for not simply using the click event?

Comment: @Archer There was (it was highlighting some text/elements after it opened the window), but I just found a way to make the simple `.click()` work. I just knew from this that my logic on event handlers in this way, was wrong, so I felt like I really needed to clear that up before I moved on with my coding.

Comment: @Pointy (and you too, Archer) Thank you, Sir(s). Now I understand, it just doesn't work that way (which also explains why I couldn't find anything on it). If you put an answer, I'll be happy to upvote and accept!